# Adding confidence level to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am putting together some summary stats of a dataframe about biomass at different sights. Here's some dummy data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
Reach = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c','b','c','a'),
Bio = c(12, 11, 10.4, 10, 12.5, 14, 12, 17, 17.5, 17.3, 16.2))
```

I have created a table in which to capture summary stats:

```
sumstats<- data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=4))
colnames(sumstats) <- c("Total.Fish", "Mean.Fish", "St.Dev", "95%.Conf")
```

Completing the first three columns is easy enough

```
sumstats$Total.Fish<- sum(df1$Bio)
sumstats$Mean.Fish<- mean(df1$Bio)
sumstats$St.Dev <- sd(df1$Bio)
```

But the last one is giving me some bother. To my understanding there isn't a function in base R which computes the 95% confidence level. I have found that I can compute it using a Z Test in BSDA:

```
library(BSDA)
test1<- z.test(df1$Bio, sigma.x=(mean(df1$Bio)), conf.level = 0.95)
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the outputs of that into my dataframe. The output of the Z test is a list, one of the list items is the confidence level.

If I print the confidence level line of that list it shows several number, my summary stats dataframe needs the first one (5.74217 in this case).
So my question is either:

1. how do I get just part of the outputs from the z test into my dataframe
2. is there an easier way to calculate the 95% condeince level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think you should be using a *Z*-test. You would use that if you were comparing your sample to a population with known mean and standard deviation, which is not the case. Also, you use sample mean to specify the population standard deviation (`sigma.x`) which is certainly not correct.

1. Just for completeness, you could get the confidence interval lower bound with `test1$conf.int[1]`, but don't do that.
2. You can use a *t*-test to find the confidence interval for your sample mean and the confidence interval can be obtained in a similar manner as for the `z.test` output:

```r
test <- t.test(df1$Bio)
sumstats$Conf.Int.Lower <- test$conf.int[1]
```

Please note that for the *t*-test results to be reliable, your data should be *normally distributed* which it rather isn't. So treat the results with caution. Alternatively, you might use a non-parametric test, such as the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

I am not sure why you are interested only in the lower CI bound. In any case, you can get the upper bound almost the same way:

```r
sumstats$Conf.Int.Upper <- test$conf.int[2]
```

Comment: This works a treat and thanks for setting me straight on the Z-Test!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one directly from R for Data Science by Hadley Wickham. First he creates a function for mean CI, makes a randomly simulated uniform distribution, and finally runs the function on the uniform data. I have only added one thing: a random seed to replicate what you see here:

```
#### Set Random Seed ####
set.seed(1)

#### Mean CI Function ####
mean_ci <- function(x, conf = 0.95) { 
  se <- sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)) 
  alpha <- 1 - conf 
  mean(x) + se * qnorm(c(alpha / 2, 1 - alpha / 2)) 
} 

#### Create Uniform Distribution of 100 Values ####
x <- runif(100) 

#### Calculate Mean CI ####
mean_ci(x)
```

Which gets you this:

```
[1] 0.4654014 0.5702927
```

Of course other versions of confidence intervals may vary a lot, so I have only used this version here.